# Не работает атрибут css cursor: url()

Tags: css, веб-программирование, cursor

[image: То что показывает браузер в стилях]

Так же пробовал сделать svg формат курсора, с ним было тоже самое, с svg форматом как я понял нужно указывать дополнительно длину и ширину.

```css
.OurServices__link {
    text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'OpenSansSemiBold', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #212121;
  border: 2px solid #212121;
  padding: 18px 13px;
  margin-top: 22px;
  cursor: url(../images/hand.png);
}
```

```html
<a class="OurServices__link" href="#"> Read more </a>
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поробуйте указать стандарт - cursor: url(../images/hand.png), pointer; и посмотрите - если работает поинтер, значит с путями или форматом не то.

*Internet Explorer в качестве формата файла курсора поддерживает CUR и ANI. Firefox, Chrome, Safari поддерживают форматы CUR, PNG, GIF, JPG. Opera не работает с файлами курсора.

Comment: Благодарю, при добавлении pointer заработала картинка.

Comment: Рад, пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0):

Я проверял код на такие проблемы и победил:
1)Формат подходит браузеру (png/cur/...) (IE не поддерживает cur, Opera не поддерживает ни один формат пользовательского курсора(*через 20минут выяснилось, что в opera url() работает...*))
2)Размер png больше 32px в одном из измерений
3)"cursor: ..." относится не к нужному объекту (а, например, к одному параграфу, вместо body)
4)Нет "запасного варианта" после url() через запятую(т.е. "cursor: url(), auto")

Comment: Шок: в Opera url() заработал...

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у вас есть другие вопросы, вы можете задать их нажав кнопку «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Дополнительно вы можете [добавить вознаграждение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), чтобы привлечь к вопросу больше внимания, когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет достаточного уровня. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/695393)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).